# Android Studio: Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:compileGroovy'

Tags: android-studio, gradle, groovy

I have an error when I`ll trying push project to git.

```
Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:compileGroovy'.

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit  Unsupported class file major version 57
```

Anyone know what how fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. It is necessary to add the following line to the gradle.properties file

org.gradle.java.home = / Library / Java / JavaVirtualMachines / jdk1.8.0_241.jdk / Contents / Home

Only the path to jdk needs to be looked specifically at your machine